# Using pymeshlab from python, how to get the faces selected by the filter compute_selection_by_self_intersections_per_face()?

Tags: python, 3d, self, pymeshlab

I have a 3d object with self intersections. I load it with meshlab and when I apply the **Select Self Intersection Face filter**, it selects the faces with self intersections.

Applying the same method with pymeshlab, loading the object applying the filter **compute_selection_by_self_intersections_per_face** does not return any selected faces. How can I get the faces that the filter have selected.

At the end of the next example when I call **ms.current_mesh().selected_face_number()** it returns zero

```
import pymeshlab

ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh('test.obj')                          
ms.compute_selection_by_self_intersections_per_face()
# ms.current_mesh().face_selection_array()
print(ms.current_mesh().selected_face_number())
```

Answer (score -1):

Not working due to a syntax error of the rgb assignment...trying to fix it...but you get the idea...

ms.compute_selection_by_color_per_face(colorspace=0, color=[125;125;125;255],  inclusive=False, percentrh=0.2, percentgs=0.2, percentbv=0.2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).